# Block bids and offers in electricity markets

Tags: power-supply, electricity

Why are offer curves and willingness-to-pay (or bidding) curves represented as blocks in electricity markets? What does each block signify?

I'm trying to simulate an electricity market using MATPOWER and came across this section. I'm trying to figure out what the block offers and bids mean in Step 1.
[image]

Here's an example from the manual:
[image]

Comment: Can you give a reference? Not quite sure what you mean with "blocks".

Comment: your question is a financial or marketing question, not an electrical engineering question

Comment: No its a topic of Science under Electrical Energy not just marketting  @jsotola although not a very technical question, it will lead to personal development for EE's interested.

Answer (score 2):

Blocks refer to a minimum of 1 hr but blocks can be any multiple of this at different Power Qty and price rates.  So the bidding is real-time and quite complex but favours the supplier to optimize profits.

*By the EPEX regulations, the minimal order size for Germany and Austria is 0.1 MW for a one hour block and the minimal price  difference  between  different  orders  is  0.1  EUR/MWh.*  2*

I recall it is an example of supply and demand fluctuations and characterized by Nash equations on game theory.

### Refs

- 1 https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360544210001386#aep-keywords-id7
- 2* https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.00372.pdf

Comment: Hi Tony, I understand that blocks are different quantities of power at different prices. I don't understand what that means at each node. From the second figure in my question, each load has 3 blocks of bids and each generator has 3 blocks of offers. Does that represent different bids from various consumers (which doesn't explain different offers from the same generator)? Or something else I'm missing?

Comment: the 3 blocks are different daily times for peak, mid and off-peak with 6 gen nodes for offers at each block time and 3 load nodes with a bid for each load at each time block.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest double auction like one-period economic dispatch (OPED) clear the market for one time unit, like 15:00 ~ 16:00. It is not necessary for all participants to submit bid/offer curves. You can just state a quantity and a price, which is used in the figure.

Usually, there are inter-temporal constraints and costs in electricity generations. For example, the ramping speed of a steam turbine is slower than a gas turbine. It comes with an additional cost if a furnace is shut down or ignited besides fuel costs. So, these costs are not taken into consideration in OPED. Unit commitment can be used to incorporate start, shut down and ramping decisions into consideration. A block order is one way to express your bid/offer regarding inter-temporal preferences. For example, to express your plan for three time units 15:00 ~ 18:00.

The figure is a bit confusing. I think the author uses "time unit" and "block" interchangeably. Block orders are widely used in European day-ahead electricity markets. There is a [short introduction to block orders](https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/trading/Day-ahead-trading/Order-types/Block-bid/) in the website of NordPool. It says:

> A block order consists of a specified volume and price for a certain number of consecutive hours within the same day.

In practice, the construction of block orders is extremely complex with all kinds of economic and technical factors considered.

It requires lots of techniques from operations research. I wrote an answer in [Operations Research, Stack Exchange](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/4028/3163), providing a good starting point if someone is interested in electricity market trading.